# XSD import with element name clash

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am trying to bring together two XSD files coming from different sources with a name clash for one element name. When creating an XML file using those XSD files I get the error message

> "Element title is not allowed here"

where title is the element name causing the name clash.

This is the 1st XSD **Meldeamt.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="http://services.meldeamt.gov.at/people"
xmlns="http://services.meldeamt.gov.at/people"
version="2.1">

  <xsd:element name="title">
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="citizen"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="immigrant"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Here is the second XSD **CalTech.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://www.caltech.at/hr"
        xmlns="http://www.caltech.at/hr"
        xmlns:registry="http://services.meldeamt.gov.at/people"
        version="2.1">

<xsd:import schemaLocation="Meldeamt.xsd" namespace="http://services.meldeamt.gov.at/people" />

<xsd:element name="CalTech">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="Staff"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="Staff">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="Employee"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="Employee">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="firstName"/>
            <xsd:element ref="name"/>
            <xsd:element ref="title" />
            <xsd:element ref="registry:title"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string">
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="Ph.D." />
            <xsd:enumeration value="Master" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="firstName" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>

</xsd:schema>
```

Here is the **Test.xml** using above XSDs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<cal:CalTech xmlns:cal="http://www.caltech.at/hr"
     xmlns:meldeamt="http://services.meldeamt.gov.at/people"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.caltech.at/hr CalTech.xsd
     http://services.meldeamt.gov.at/people Meldeamt.xsd">

<cal:Staff>
    <cal:Employee id="a471">
        <cal:firstName>John</cal:firstName>
        <cal:name>Connor</cal:name>
        <cal:title>Ph.D.</cal:title>
        <meldeamt:title>immigrant</meldeamt:title>
    </cal:Employee>
</cal:Staff>

</cal:CalTech>
```

For the first title element, `cal:title`, I get the error message

> Element cal:title is not allowed here

I'm testing the XML in IntelliJ Idea.
If I change the name of `cal:title` to `cal:title1` in CalTech.xsd and Text.xml, the error message disappears, and everything works fine, including validation of the content.

I don't know what I'm missing here.

Comment: The original cause for the error appears to be a bug in IntelliJ Idea which complains about the <cal:title> element while the Xerces parser accepts the input XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually did a fine job of setting up the machinery to employ namespaces to avoid name clashes.  Just a minor declaration mistake to fix and all will be well...

In CalTech.xsd, change

```
<xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string">
```

to

```
<xsd:element name="title">
```

because an element declaration cannot have both a `@type` attribute and an anonymous type child element.

Then, your XML file will validate successfully against your XSDs.

BTW, the error you should have received should have look more along the lines of what Xerces provides:

> [Error] CalTech.xsd:38:47: src-element.3: Element 'title' has both a
>   'type' attribute and a 'anonymous type' child. Only one of these is
>   allowed for an element.

Comment: Yes, the Xerces error message indeed would have been more helpful. It's working now, thank you!